# remove keyword frequency from a key phrase which has the same keyword

Tags: python

I have a list of keyword frequency as the following, the frequency is counted by matching the keyword to the responses. However, I want to remove the frequency of "public health", "health issue", and "health condition" from "health". Also, remove the frequency of "public health officials" from the "public health". I am wondering, how can I do this in Python？

| keyword | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| health | 56 |
| healthcare | 23 |
| health condition | 5 |
| health issue | 4 |
| public health | 7 |
| public health official | 2 |

Comment: Can you show us the `minimum code` you've tried? along with where you got stuck?

Comment: Yep, there is no need to consolidate the information, just to subtract the keyword frequency from the frequency of the key phrase that already has that keyword.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Build on the previous answer, I figure it out as the following:

1. Tokenize the keyword and find the max keyword length
2. Loop through the keyword column from the max length to a single word
3. Remove duplicated keyword frequency if keywords with smaller length appear within a
   bigger keyphrase
4. Update the previous dataframe

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import spacy

   import en_core_web_md
   nlp = en_core_web_md.load()

   df = .....
   df_3 = df

   # find the max length of the column value
   max_length = df["keyword"].map(lambda x: len(nlp(x))).max()

   length = max_length

   # loop until the length ends with column value that only have one word
   while length > 1 :

     element = []
     value = []
     element_2 = []
     value_2 = []
     element_3 = []
     value_3 = []

     # select column value by different length
     for index, row in df_3.iterrows():
         a = len(nlp(row["keyword"]))
         if a == length:
             element.append(row["keyword"])
             value.append(row["frequency"])
         if a < length:
             element_2.append(row["keyword"])
             value_2.append(row["frequency"])
         if a > length:
             element_3.append(row["keyword"])
             value_3.append(row["frequency"])

     d_1 = dict(zip(element, value))
     d_2 = dict(zip(element_2, value_2))
     d_3 = dict(zip(element_3, value_3))

     # remove duplicated keyword frequency if keyword with smaller length 
     appear in key phrase with bigger length

     for key1, value1 in d_1.items():
     for key2, value2 in d_2.items():
         if key2 in key1:
             d_2[key2] = value2-value1


     new_key = []
     new_value = []

     # update the original dataframe
     for key, value in d_2.items():
         new_key.append(key)
         new_value.append(value)
     for key, value in d_1.items():
         new_key.append(key)
         new_value.append(value)
     for key, value in d_3.items():
         new_key.append(key)
         new_value.append(value)

     df_3 = pd.DataFrame({"keyword":new_key, "frequency":new_value})

     length -= 1
   ```

The answer looks pretty dump, welcome one more elegant~

Answer (score -1):

With this script, you can specify the value to substract from with the variable `ele`.

Then every element that starts with the `ele` will be substracted.
For public health, you would just mirror the same code with a  `ele = "public health"` before.

```
d = {
    "health" : 56,
    "healthcare" : 23,
    "health condition" : 5,
    "health issue" : 4,
    "public health" : 7,
    "public health official" : 2,  
}

ele = "health"

for key, value in d.items():
    if (key != ele) or not key.startswith("ele"):
        d[ele] -= value

print(d[ele]) #-41
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions that should not have been asked.
We don't want Stack Overflow to be a homework service.

Comment: Thank you Lukas, based on your answer, I find a way to systemize it